# Finding the fundamental Pell solution from a system of Pell-like equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Assume $d$ is a non-square integer, and $r,s,t,w$ are integers, and $n$ and $m $ are integers with $n,m \neq 0,\pm 1$, satisfying the system of Pell-like equations
\begin{align}
r^2-ds^2 &= m,  \\
t^2-dw^2 &= mn.
\end{align}
Can I use this information [and nothing else] to determine the fundamental solution $(u,v)$ to the Pell equation
$$U^2-dV^2=1$$
?

Comment: If this were true in general, it would be trivial to take any $r,s$ and generate an $m$, then take $2r, 2s$ for $t, w$ and find fundamental solutions quickly. So I rather doubt it.

Comment: @Macavity: Good point…